# Implementing collision in 3D

Tags: collision-detection, lwjgl, collision

Is there an "easy" way to detect if two objects, which can't be aproximated to Cuboid, intersects?

I use LWJGL library, and wanted to implement simple collision recognition. I don't want to use JBullet, because it's too difficult to my current skills and needs, and unfortunately my objects have irregular shapes, so i can't use AABB collision detection.

I have vertices of objects stored in arrays(parsed from .obj)
Don't you know some way to check if they intersects?

Comment: No. Also, you can use AABB collision detection on any shape, irregular or not.

Comment: Ok, but the AABB boxes will be rectangular itself, and I want to keep more or less the shape of my object.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use AABBs for rough collisions. If you really want to have more precise collision, you can proceed to check those prefiltered entities, but there is no really "simple" way to do that.
If you do not want to use a library, you will have to check whether one cube includes vertices of another for all possible arrangements of shapes. It should be doaable with some geometry, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a collection of AABBs, spheres, and cylinders to approximate the shape of each object. Depending on the complexity of the model it may require a significant amount of work to manually define the various collision volumes.

A tree could use a cylinder for the trunk and a sphere for the foliage. A truck could use three cubes, one for the front, a second for the cab, and a third for the bed. A collision between the two would be resolved by checking the trunk and foliage against the front, cab, and bed of the truck.